# How Can I Make this Python Code Better/More Elegant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gspread

I wrote a script in Python to query the RESTful API of my company's Jira instance for certain information to be uploaded to a Google Doc. Admittedly, I'm not a professional programmer and am still an amateur at best. How can I clean this code up and make it more Pythonic and elegant?

```
cell = 2

for issue in issues:
    title = issue.fields.customfield_xxxx
    first_name = issue.fields.customfield_xxxx
    last_name = issue.fields.customfield_xxxx
    email = issue.fields.customfield_xxxx
    username = first_name[0] + last_name
    wks.update_acell('A{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(first_name))
    wks.update_acell('B{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(last_name))
    wks.update_acell('C{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(title))
    wks.update_acell('I{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(email))
    wks.update_acell('E{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(
       username + "@company.com"))
    wks.update_acell('F{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(username))
    wks.update_acell('H{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(
       first_name + " " + last_name))
   wks.update_acell('G{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(
       first_name + " " + last_name))
   wks.update_acell('J{}'.format(cell), '{}'.format(x))

cell += 1
```

Comment: This question would probably work much better on code view: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  They accept people's, **working** code, and could help you improve it. I suggest moving it there.

Comment: Great idea. Thank you!

Comment: you're very welcome :) I have found their reviewing service invaluable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you could use a for loop to clean up your code and save some typing

```
    cellfields = [['a',first_name],['b',last_name]['c',title]] ... etc
    for fields in cellfields:
        wks.update_acell(fields[0] + str(cell), fields[1])
```

sorry for the poor variable naming. :/

Comment: Good suggestion, but this type of question really doesn't belong here, and so they should be left alone.